# Wireless Router Multihoming?

Tags: wireless, network, networking

Here's the scenario:

- One outdoor equipment cabinet with seven different 100 Mbps carrier feeds

  - Currently, no trailers are wired. The point of this is to avoid running cable to each trailer
- Seven trailers, each with their own IP blocks
- Each trailer has to have a wireless network

Instead of placing seven wireless routers inside the outdoor equipment cabinet, is it possible to multihome the carrier feeds at one wireless router and then have each trailer use the same wireless router on a different subnet?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Did you really mean 100Gps?  How far are the trailers from the cabinet?

Comment: Do you mean WAPs, not routers? Wireless routers are off-topic consumer-grade devices.

Comment: @RonTrunk - sorry, I meant 100 Mbps; the question has been edited.  I have not been onsite but I have been told they are about 100 yards away.

Comment: @RonMaupin - I'm looking for the best solution, whether that is WAPs or a consumer-grade wireless router.

Comment: Well, we cannot help with consumer-grade devices, nor can we make any product recommendations. If the trailers are metal, you are going to have a problem at 100 yards, and you will need several WAPs to get seven different SSIDs to properly work. This sounds like you are going to need to have someone perform a wireless site survey. You need to identify interference sources to determine the frequencies placement, power levels, etc.

Comment: Remember that Wi-Fi is bidirectional, and the antenna and radio in client devices is usually nearly as good as what you have in the WAP.

Comment: Will the trailers have their own access points?  Or will the cabinet be talking to clients directly?

Comment: @RonTrunk - we aren't dedicated to either solution yet, so whichever would be more effective works for us

Comment: Many enterprise APs can support 8 or more SSIDs. So that shouldn't be an issue. Depending on site layout, sector antennas can be used to limit the overlap using 2 or more APs. The biggest issue will be the end nodes (trailers) potentially stepping on each other.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

100 yards can be bridged in several ways:

- wireless using directional, high-gain outdoor antennas
- wired using copper - 100 m is the limit for solid-core cable (90 m solid-core, 10 m braided/patch), so this'll be tight - *cheapest variant*
- wired using fiber - 100 yards is no distance for fiber, multi-mode will do easily - *most reliable and scalable variant, my preference in any case*

The simple setup would be to bridge each feed to one trailer and redistribute inside the trailer by local router/WAP. Depending on the trailer walls you might also get away with direct links - directional antennas are most probably required on the feed side - but this may well not work at all or only unreliably.

The sophisticated setup would be a central router in or near the feed cabinet (or two for redundancy) and load-balancing distribution to the trailer WAPs. This would also call for gigabit bridging to leverage the load balancing. Gigabit on copper or fiber is about the same price as 100 Mbit/s, so I'd use that road anyway.

If cost is an issue the sophisticated setup has the potential to lose some/most of the feeds - 2x 100 Mbit/s should be plenty for normal usage.